# count unique values within nested list in python

Tags: python-2.7, count, unique, nested-lists

I have this list:

```
list = [[['aa08'], ['aao8'], ['bb01'], ['bb08'], ['cc04'], ['cc08']],
 [['aa08'], ['bb01'], ['bb08'], ['bb08'], ['bb08'], ['aao1']],
 [['cc04'], ['cc01'], ['cc08'], ['bb01'], ['aa08'], ['cc01']],
 [['aa08'], ['aao8'], ['bb01'], ['bbo8'], ['cc04'], ['cc08']],
 [['aa08'], ['bb01'], ['bb08'], ['bb08'], ['bb08'], ['aao1']],
 [['cc04'], ['cc01'], ['cc08'], ['bb01'], ['aa08'], ['cc01']]]
```

and I´m triying to extract unique occurrences of each value, such as:

```
aa08 = 8
bb01 = 6
bb08 = 8
cc04 = 4
cc08 = 4
cc01 = 4
```

I have tried some functions but they were not appropriate to my case. How can I do this in a simple way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/collections.html). You'll want to flatten the list first. Example:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> l = [1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3]
>>> c = Counter(l)
>>> c.keys()
dict_keys([1, 2, 3])
>>> c.values()
dict_values([2, 3, 4])
```